# Program to reverse order of words in a string printing reversed string incorrectly

Tags: c, string, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program that takes an entered string and reverses the order of words. It also counts how many words are in a statement. So if "batman and robin" was entered, it would print:

```
robin and batman
words in statement: 3
```

my program mostly works, but it prints in a strange way. This would be the output for "batman and robin" in the program I've written:

```
robin

and batman

words in statement: 2
```

I don't know why there's an extra newline that separates the first word from the rest. No matter what I input, the first word is always separated from the rest and the count is one off. I'm not sure where the extra newline is coming from. I could fix the count problem by just adding one to the count before I print, but I'm trying to find a better solution.

My code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void) {
char ent[50], rev[50];
int length, i = 0, start, end, j = 0, count = 0, k;

printf("Enter a statement: ");
fgets(ent, 50, stdin);
//printf("%s\n", ent);

length = strlen(ent);
start = length - 1;
end = length - 1;


while (start > 0) {
    if (ent[start] == ' ') {
        i = start + 1;
        count++; 

        while (i <= end) {
            rev[j] = ent[i];
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        rev[j++] = ' ';
        end = start - 1;
    }
    start--;
}

for (i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
    rev[j] = ent[i];
    j++;
}

rev[j] = '\0';
//count = count + 1;

printf("Reversed statement: %s\n", rev);
printf("Words in statement: %d\n", count);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Instead of writing `fgets(ent, 50, stdin);`, you can write `fgets(ent, sizeof ent, stdin);`. This has the advantage that if you ever change the size of `ent`, then you will only have to change one number, not two. If you don't do this, then you risk having a bug if you change the number in one place, but forget to change it in the other place, too.

Answer (score 0):

If the function `fgets` reads a newline character, then it will also write it into the string.

Due to this, the first word that you will write to `rev` is not `"robin"`, but rather `"robin\n"`. That is what is causing the undesired output that you posted.

You can either deal with the newline character, or simply remove it immediately after calling `fgets`. See this question on what the best ways are to remove the newline character:

[Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471)